# Should I set up a custom user-agent for Simplepie

Tags: php, feed, simplepie

I'm creating a feed aggregator. I will be crawling blogs and checking sometimes every hour or every two hours to see if they have new posts. I am using Simplepie for this.

I want to know if I should change the custom user-agent that Simplepie has (`SIMPLEPIE_USERAGENT`). Also, what are best practices for user-agents if I should change it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you should, otherwise they might start complaining about it to the SimplePie maintainer (i.e. me :) ). Using a custom useragent lets them know who to contact if something breaks.

The ideal format is "Your Program Name/1.0" where 1.0 is the version. You can also include URLs (put a + in front of them if you do so) and contact addresses, making it "Your Program Name/1.0 (+http://example.com/)"

Answer (score 1):

Should you change it? Well, that depends on what you're doing. Some sites will block you based on the UA. That's their right.

If you're trying to scrape data and don't care about obeying rules, then you can change it to whatever you want.

Best practice is to identify yourself and obey robots.txt

Comment: Well, my website is legit and I would be mostly going through sites that are registered with me. I actually don't want them to block me thinking that I'm fake.

Answer (score 0):

I always put the name of my app as the user agent, that way server admins can contact me if my script ever causes problems with their server. (Which is the only reason anybody would care)